# Function removes items from localStorage only if run manually

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for advice/tips on how to fix a function that is supposed to remove items from localStorage. I'm following a tutorial by John Smilga that I found on Youtube. Although I've modeled my code on his, apparently, I have missed something.

This function works perfectly well if I run it manually from the console and pass in the id of the item that I want to remove from localStorage.

```
function removeFromLocalStorage(id) {
  console.log(id);
  let storageItems = getLocalStorage();
  console.log(storageItems);
  storageItems = storageItems.filter(function(singleItem) {
    if (singleItem.id !== id) {
      return singleItem;
    }
  })
  console.log(storageItems);
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(storageItems));
}
```

However, when this function is triggered by the deleteItem() function, it refuses to remove the item from localStorage. It still works, there are a bunch of console.logs in it that track its execution, and I can check that it receives the correct item id as the argument, but for some reason it doesn't filter out the item that needs to be removed. I am completely lost and have no idea how to identify the problem. I can't debug it with console.logs as I usually do. I will be very grateful if you help me find the problem. Any advice will be appreciated.

In case the entire code is needed, please find it below.

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".app__form");
const alert = document.querySelector(".app__alert");
const input = document.querySelector(".app__input");
const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".app__submit-btn");
const itemsContainer = document.querySelector(".app__items-container");
const itemsList = document.querySelector(".app__items-list");
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".app__clear-btn");

let editElement;
let editFlag = false;
let editId = "";

form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearItems);

function addItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999);
  if (input.value && !editFlag) {
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.classList.add("app__item");
    const attr = document.createAttribute("data-id");
    attr.value = id;
    item.setAttributeNode(attr);
    item.innerHTML = `<p class='app__item-text'>${input.value}</p>
    <div class='app__item-btn-cont'>
      <button class='app__item-btn app__item-btn--edit'>edit</button>
      <button class='app__item-btn app__item-btn--delete'>delete</button>
    </div>`
    const editBtn = item.querySelector(".app__item-btn--edit");
    const deleteBtn = item.querySelector(".app__item-btn--delete");
    editBtn.addEventListener("click", editItem);
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
    itemsList.appendChild(item);
    displayAlert("item added", "success");
    addToLocalStorage(id, input.value);
    setBackToDefault();
    itemsContainer.classList.add("app__items-container--visible");
  } else if (input.value && editFlag) {
    editElement.textContent = input.value;
    // edit local storage
    editLocalStorage(editId, input.value);
    setBackToDefault();
    displayAlert("item edited", "success");
  } else {
    displayAlert("empty field", "warning");
  }
}

function setBackToDefault() {
  input.value = "";
  editFlag = false;
  editId = "";
  submitBtn.textContent = "Submit";
  submitBtn.className = "app__submit-btn";
}

function displayAlert(text, action) {
  alert.textContent = text;
  alert.classList.add(`app__alert--${action}`);
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert.textContent = "";
    alert.classList.remove(`app__alert--${action}`);
  }, 700)
}

function clearItems() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".app__item");
  if (items.length > 0) {
    items.forEach(function(singleItem) {
      itemsList.removeChild(singleItem);
    })
    itemsContainer.classList.remove("app__items-container--visible");
    displayAlert("items cleared", "cleared");
    setBackToDefault();
  }
}

function editItem(e) {
  const item = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
  editElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  editId = item.dataset.id;
  editFlag = true;
  input.value = editElement.textContent;
  submitBtn.textContent = "Edit";
  submitBtn.classList.add("app__submit-btn--edit");
  input.focus();

}

function deleteItem(e) {
  const item = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
  const itemId = item.dataset.id;

  removeFromLocalStorage(itemId);
  displayAlert("item removed", "cleared");
  setBackToDefault();
  itemsList.removeChild(item);
  if (itemsList.children.length === 0) {
    itemsContainer.classList.remove("app__items-container--visible");
  }
}

function addToLocalStorage(id, value) {
  const itemsObj = {id: id, value: input.value};
  let storageItems = getLocalStorage();
  storageItems.push(itemsObj);
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(storageItems));


}


function removeFromLocalStorage(id) {
  console.log(id);
  let storageItems = getLocalStorage();
  console.log(storageItems);
  storageItems = storageItems.filter(function(singleItem) {
    if (singleItem.id !== id) {
      return singleItem;
    }
  })
  console.log(storageItems);
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(storageItems));
}

function editLocalStorage(id, value) {

}

function getLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("list") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list")) : [];
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 75px auto 0;
}

.app__title {
  text-align: center;
  /* color: #1B5D81; */
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #377FB4;
}


.app__alert {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #215884;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 23px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.app__alert--warning {
  background-color: rgba(243, 117, 66, 0.2);
  color: #006699;
}

.app__alert--success {
  background-color: rgba(165, 237, 92, 0.4);
  color: #3333ff;
}

.app__alert--cleared {
  background-color: #a978da;
  color: white;
}

.app__input-btn-cont {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.app__input {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-right: none;
  border: 1px solid #67B5E2;
  background-color: #EDF9FF;
}

.app__input:focus {
  outline: transparent;
}

.app__submit-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: #67B5E2;
  border: 1px solid #67B5E2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.7s;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

.app__submit-btn--edit {
  background-color: #95CB5D;
}

.app__submit-btn:active {
  width: 19.9%;
  padding: 0 0;
}

.app__submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #377FB4;
}

.app__submit-btn--edit:hover {
  background-color: #81AF51;
}

.app__items-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* transition: 0.7s; */
}

.app__items-container--visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.app__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.app__item:hover {
  background-color: #b9e2fa;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.app__item-text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1B5D81;
}

.app__item-btn-cont {
  display: flex;
}

.app__item-btn-img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.app__item-btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.app__item-btn--edit {
  margin-right: 45px;
  color: #2c800f;
}

.app__item-btn--delete {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: rgb(243, 117, 66);
}

.app__clear-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(243, 117, 66);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.app__clear-btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(243, 117, 66);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="list.css">
    <title>To Do List App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="app">
      <form class="app__form">
        <p class="app__alert"></p>
        <h2 class="app__title">To Do List</h2>
          <div class="app__input-btn-cont">
            <input class="app__input" type="text" id="todo" placeholder="do stuff">
            <button class="app__submit-btn">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </form>
      <div class="app__items-container">
        <div class="app__items-list">
        </div>
        <button class="app__clear-btn">Clear Items</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="list.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are just probably using the wrong way Localstorage object? There's already a removeItem(key) method. Why should you loop and filter all localStorage values? Maybe because you're not using the correct way to index Localstorage Items and should setItem(key, value) using your unique id as key?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. @Abd Ash has identified a more immediate problem, but your solution should work too, I've just never used this method before. Will give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine you just used the wrong comparison operator.

In your case you are comparing 2 IDs (operands) to see if they match up, so you should use normal operators such as (==, !=), but instead in your case, you have used strict operators which are used to compare the operand type and the operand itself.

You can learn more about [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators) here.

Ultimatly,
In your function removeFromLocalStorage(id), you have an extra equal sign in your if function.
Instead of:

```
if (singleItem.id !== id) {
  return singleItem;}
```

It should be:

```
if (singleItem.id != id) {
  return singleItem;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: JavaScript has two equality operators, `==` and `===`. The former will use coercion to convert the right side of the operation to the same type as the left. The latter will return false if the two sides are not the same type.

Comment: He's using a "Strict not equal" operator. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators Scroll down to "Comparison Operators" to read about this specific one.

Comment: But this *is* most likely actually the correct answer. The behaviour of the OP's function will differentiate between a Number and String passed for id. This won't.

Comment: Wow! It actually does the trick! Thank you so much for helping me with this, I've struggled for quite a while with this thing.

Comment: @EchoSierra Your function `deleteItem` gets `id` from `const itemId = item.dataset.id;`, but all `dataset` elements are strings, even if you assigned a Number to them previously. So that's where the difference between `!=` and `!==` will kick in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm aware of the "Strict not equal" but for this example he is actually comparing the actual value of the ids, not their type. This is why I suggested this edit.

Comment: You really should include the definition of strict not equal in the answer so that the OP can learn from it, rather than saying "you just have a small unnoticed error".

Comment: @The Vee Aha, got it, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know about this, will do my reading now

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Thank you for the explanation! Will definitely have to learn more about  this

Comment: @srWebDev Thank you for the link, it's going to come in handy!